# Toggle Hide/Show sidebar jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

i can't figure out why the toggle isn't working in my code. This should hide the sidebar when i click on the navbutton, but it doesn't. Thank you very much for reading my question.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#navbutton').click(function() {
$('#sidebar').toggle('slow');
});
```

**HTML/PHP (Look only between the < button > < /button> tag.**

```
                <div id="header">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"id="navbutton">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                </button>

                <div id="title">
                <a href="home.php" style="color:#fafafa;text-decoration:none;">Trigger</div>
                <div id="MenuInHeader"><ul><li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-external-link fa-fw"></i> Logout</a></li></ul></div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
position:absolute;
left:0;
width:200px;
height:100%;
background:#5e5e5e;
opacity:0.9;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but there is a missing space before id="navbutton".

Comment: Where is `#sidebar` in your HTML???

Comment: Thank you for you're help, but that isn't the problem, I think the missing space is happened when I entered the code in stackoverflow. In my code its not missing a space, thank you anyway.

Comment: Do I have to code in in my HTML?

Comment: I dont see an element with id=sidebar in your HTML?Is there one?

Comment: Sorry, Yes there is one under below the header div, there is a id sidebar div

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/5aDUM/

Comment: Yes it works there, but not in my site, thats the weird one. I have exactly the same code

Comment: Do you include jquery?

Comment: yes, like this <script src="js/hidesidebar.js"></script>

Comment: Is what is posted the entire contents of hidesidebar.js? You need to include jQuery in your source code before hidesidebar.js is loaded.

Comment: @shrmn, THX for your answer, that was it. I didn't include <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Meaning load jQuery before your script. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/hidesidebar.js"></script> in that order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `div` to your mark up

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

And wrap your js in `document.ready`

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#navbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         $('#sidebar').toggle('slow');
   });

});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/xagol/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple hide/show sidebar script for you to get the idea:

```
<div id="sidebar" style="height:600px; width:100px; right:-75px; position:absolute; background-color:black;">
//sidebar styling
</div>




<script>
$('#sidebar').hover(function() {
$('#sidebar').stop().animate({'right' : '0px'}, 250);
}, function() {
$('#sidebar').stop().animate({'right' : '-75px'}, 350); 
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XTDHx/

Comment: I tried your script, but this didn't work either for my code. I don't know where it goes wrong...

Comment: edited with working example, if you cannot get it to work you mustn't have loaded jQuery correctly.